# Failed to refresh gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1: Unknown method ScalaCompileOptions.getForce()

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle-based project primarily with Java code and a small subproject with Scala (a Gatling-based performance test).

I recently upgraded Gradle wrapper to v2.12, which is currently the latest version. 
And today I just updated IntelliJ Idea from v15 to v2016.1.

When I try to refresh the project from the Gradle files in Idea, I get this error.

```
Error:Cause: org.gradle.api.tasks.scala.ScalaCompileOptions.getForce()Ljava/lang/String;
```

I noticed when searching on Google, that the method getForce() (returning a String) apparently has been replaced by isForce() (returning a boolean).

If i downgrade Gradle wrapper to v2.11 the problem disappears.
Is there anything else I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: Does everything work from the command line? Have you tried 'Invalidate  Caches / Restart..'  in idea?

Comment: I just tried  'Invalidate Caches / Restart..' in IDEA - it makes no difference, the problem remains.

Comment: Are you able to execute gradle from the command line? If the same problem occures form the cli than it's not a problem of your IDE.

Comment: I have seen no similar issue from the command line. Running e.g. "gradle cleanIdea idea" which performs similar functionality (but generates an older format of IDEA files) runs fine.

Answer (score 3):

I guess there is nothing except downgrade you can do. Just report your problem on [Jetbrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/)

Comment: It turns out the problem had already been reported. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152976

Comment: yep. so you have to wait till it will be fixed

Comment: The issue is apparently fixed now, so I guess it will be included in the next 2016.1.X release.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed as per release notes published in https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+2016.1+145.844.1+Release+Notes. See IDEA-152976.

One needs to switch to IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1 145.844.1

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the `Scala` `plugin` in `intellij` solved the problem for me.